# Delphi - idHTTP upload file using TIdMultipartFormDataStream

Tags: delphi, idhttp

I'm trying to upload a file using `TIdHTTP`. The problem is the access token gets changed when the request is sent to the server.

The access token that I'm using is `fJNhDM6TlcpeVmD8h3jFuPJS71sxwZB8bZBXajTRB5TNAcRa6PNXfv4J7mPxIvMdMhjy7oKdTLbsRYthpBCCqGVkj4vlojJ4BRBkLAVIBJ1DZAnMZD`

The API returns

`HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
OAuth "invalid_token" "Malformed access token fJNhDM6TlcpeVmD8h3jFu=\r\nPJS71sxwZB8bZBXajTRB5TNAcRa6PNXfv4J7mPxIvMdMhjy7oKdTLbsRYthpBCCqGVkj4v=\r\nlojJ4BRBkLAVIBJ1DZAnMZD"`

There is `=\r\n` added to my token twice.

My code is:

```
function TFoo.Post(const AToken, guID, AMessage, AImageFileName: string): Boolean;
var
  lParam : TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
  Result := False;
  if not FileExists(AImageFileName) then begin
    LastError := 'File not found ' + AImageFileName;
    Exit;
  end;
  ProxyCheck;
  lParam := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
  try
    lParam.AddFormField('message', AMessage);
    lParam.AddFormField('access_token', AToken);
    lParam.AddFile('source', AImageFileName);
    idHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    try
      idHTTP.Post( UrlAPI + guID + '/photos', lParam);
      Result := True;
    except;
      LastError := idHTTP.ResponseText + sLineBreak + idHTTP.Response.WWWAuthenticate.Text;
    end;
  finally
    lParam.Free;
  end;
end;
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `AddFormField()` sets the `TIdFormDataField.ContentTransfer` property to MIME's `quoted-printable` format. That is where the extra `=\r\n` is coming from.  It is a "soft" line break being inserted by `quoted-printable` every 76 characters.  Any server that supports `quoted-printable` would remove "soft" line breaks during decoding. But maybe your server does not.

If you want to disable the `quoted-printable` behavior, you can set the `ContentTransfer` property to either:

1. a blank string:

   ```
   lParam.AddFormField('access_token', AToken).ContentTransfer := '';
   ```
2. `'7bit'` (since it does not contain any non-ASCII characters):

   ```
   lParam.AddFormField('access_token', AToken).ContentTransfer := '7bit';
   ```
3. `'8bit'` or `binary`:

   ```
   lParam.AddFormField('access_token', AToken).ContentTransfer := '8bit';
   ```

   ```
   lParam.AddFormField('access_token', AToken).ContentTransfer := 'binary';
   ```

In this case, I would suggest #1.

On a side note, do not set the HTTP content type when posting a `TIdMultipartFormDataStream`.  Not only are you using the wrong media type to begin with (it should be `multipart/form-data` instead), but the `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` version of `Post()` will simply overwrite it anyway.

```
function TFoo.Post(const AToken, guID, AMessage, AImageFileName: string): Boolean;
var
  lParam : TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
  Result := False;
  if not FileExists(AImageFileName) then begin
    LastError := 'File not found ' + AImageFileName;
    Exit;
  end;
  ProxyCheck;
  lParam := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
  try
    lParam.AddFormField('message', AMessage);
    lParam.AddFormField('access_token', AToken).ContentTransfer := '';
    lParam.AddFile('source', AImageFileName);
    try
      idHTTP.Post(UrlAPI + guID + '/photos', lParam);
      Result := True;
    except;
      LastError := idHTTP.ResponseText + sLineBreak + idHTTP.Response.WWWAuthenticate.Text;
    end;
  finally
    lParam.Free;
  end;
end;
```